# Audi A4 (B8) Whine

Tags: noise, audi, a4

I've got a 1.8 TFSI A4, and it's making a whining noise.

It's audible if you rev the engine, and when driving. Very pronounced at lower speeds.

If you depress the clutch, it stops. But, if you rev it'll whine again.

Going down an enclosed street, with the windows open, when you press the clutch it stops making the noise. If you then rev'd with the clutch still disengaged it'll make the same sort of noise.

It's not the serpentine belt, or associated pulleys, because I've had that checked by a garage and with the belt removed it still made the noise.

Any idea what it might be?

Edit:

Video of engine noise: https://youtu.be/ysgOLFC_syM

Comment: What year is your Audi? I'm seeing two engines listed for it (CABA/CDHA or CABB/CDHB) ... do you know which 1.8 TFSI you have? Also, take a look at the crankshaft and have someone articulate the clutch ... does the main pulley move at all (away from the engine) ... even the slightest?

Comment: It's the CABB engine.

Comment: Forgot I'd recorded a video of the noise. This might make it a little easier to understand what sort of noise I'm experiencing. https://youtu.be/ysgOLFC_syM

Comment: Maybe I'm deaf, but I'm not hearing any abnormal noises there ... I hope someone else can hear what you are talking about.

Comment: Yeah, it's entirely probable it's just an engine noise.

Comment: A longer video that shows what you are doing with the clutch would be helpful. I'm also not hearing anything abnormal in the video you posted, although I don't own this vehicle.

Comment: To be very honest with you, it somewhat sounds like a turbo spooling, which I doubt it is.. Have you found out what it is?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the *barely* audible noise which occurs about 1/2 way through the video. You are slowly bringing the RPMs up past 1000. When you get it *just* above 1000 (probably like 1050), I hear a slight noise. This noise sounds like some kind of resonance whistle coming from the intake tract. To test this theory, take your air cleaner out and completely clean any debris which might have collected on the inlet side (from the outside of the car). Something may be in there somewhere which, when a certain amount of air flow occurs through the intake, it whistles (or makes the noise). This is the only thing I can think of as in order to hear any out of the ordinary noise, I had to turn the video sound all the way up.

Comment: I think it is just the way this engine sounds. I took it to a specialist, who did in fact highlight a failed PAS pump which has since been changed. I can't tell whether or not it's quieter, but other people are unable to hear anything out of the ordinary now. So it's probably just me being paranoid. I'm going to monitor the noise and if it does change over time, I'll get it looked at again.